# How can I best emulate the behavior of isEmpty String method with a Datetime?

Tags: apex, datetime

What is the best way to check if a Datetime is set in Apex and capture this as a boolean?

The `String` primitive data type has the convenient `isEmpty` method... How can I best emulate the behavior of this method with a Datetime?

Comment: Why not use a formula field and the `ISBLANK()` function?

Comment: That works, I suppose.  I can abstract the check as a checkbox formula field, and use it in my Apex instead...   That just smells a little odd.  :~}

Comment: But thank you!  That does solve my problem.

Comment: Other than that, you could just do a null check in Apex (i.e. `myObject.some_datetime_field__c == null`)

Comment: Right, that would also work -- requiring an if statement to assign the result to a boolean variable.

Comment: You wouldn't need an `if`, the assignment can be done directly `myBool = myObject.some_datetime_field__c == null;`

Comment: @DerekF, add your notes as an answer? I'll accept / close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can achieve this.

The easiest way is probably to just create a formula field to take care of this, the `ISBLANK()` function works on pretty much everything. It also saves you the trouble of writing (and testing) a trigger to save the calculation to a Checkbox field. Just be sure to have your formula set to treat blanks as blanks (instead of treating blanks as zeroes), if you're given the option.

Of course, if you aren't looking to persist this value (say it's a calculation that only happens one time), then a formula field isn't really a good fit. In that case, you can simply perform a check to see if your date field is null

```
// <some value> == <other value> returns a boolean result, and can be assigned to a 
// boolean variable directly
Boolean myBool = myObject.some_datetime_field__c == null;

// Of course, this will also work if you just have a variable/class attribute  of
//   type 'Date' as well. It doesn't need to be from a field on an SObject
```